# Getting error as Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpParamsOptions'

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-httpclient

So currently our project is on Angular version 4, we are trying to upgrade it to Angular 7. When I put the new http Module it started throwing  the error: `Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpParamsOptions'`.

Before this change we were using RequestOptions but now it has been deprecated from Angular 7.

Code From Angular 4:

```
   options(): RequestOptions {
     const headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
     return options;
   }
```

Code from Angular 7

```
      options(): HttpParams {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        let options = new HttpParams ({ headers: headers });
        return options;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the params in the headers, when now they are separated from the params:

So the params and the headers go in different way. So in your scenario would look something like this:

```
      options(): HttpHeaders {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
        return headers ;
      }
```

Note that I **get rid** from the `headers.append` too.

Your get now should look like:

```
headers = options();
this.http.get(url, { headers });
```

If you want params, yo do it in a separate way:

```
headers = options();
params = new HttpParams(); 
this.http.get(url, { headers , params});
```

Comment: I changed it to Following:

             options(): HttpParams{
                const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':[], 'application/json; 
                 charset=utf-8':[]});
                 return this.options;
            }

But now it throws error as "Type '() => HttpParams' is not assignable to type 'HttpParams'.
  Property 'map' is missing in type '() => HttpParams'."

Comment: Make sure you have imported the HttpHeaders from the correct path: `import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: Hello, This is my Import import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Oh! my bad, It's wrong the code I posted. The options should be HttpHeaders! I already updated the code, check that the function options return a `HttpHeaders` now

Comment: Thanks, it works for now, I will come to you again if would stuck somewhere, but it was really great help.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: now m getting error in different file where Options is being called as-
Argument of type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.

Comment: Probably you are missing the { }  inside the function: 
this.http.get(url, **{ headers }**  );

Comment: Yes Indeed I was, corrected that, really thanks for your help. :-)